# JQuery UI Autocomplete focus() being called unexpectedly in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery-ui

I've created a simple auto-complete control using JQuery UI. I have a default value for the input field that reads "Enter your keywords...". I've set up a *focus()* event that will clear the input when a user sets the focus to the input field to being typing.

In IE when you being typing and the menu displays a list of items, when picking an item from the menu item *focus()* is called again. This extra call to *focus()* only happens in IE. The side effect is that the selected menu item is cleared from the text field.

I have a very primitive solution to this by making use of the `autocomplete.focus()` event. This event is fired when the user hovers over a selected menu item. Here I can set a global boolean variable that can be used to tell the focus() event on the input field that the menu item is active/visible and thus not to clear the input value. This is a hack, of course!

Is there an alternative (less hacky!) solution to this problem?

Here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete demo</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
               // This event fires when an item from the menu is selected (in focus)
               // set some variable here to tell the focus() call to the text field not to clear the value from the input field
            },
        });

        $("#tags").focus(function () {
            // clear the input value
            $("#tags").val("");
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" value="Enter your keywords..." />
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## UPDATE

With the slight tweak to this solution and with help from the provided answer this now works in IE 8 & 9.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

    $("#tags").focus(function () {
        // clear the input value
        $("#tags").val("");

      return false;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had a similar issue and I believe we fixed it by adding a `return false;` to the `focus` method:

```
$("#tags").focus(function () {
        // clear the input value
        $("#tags").val("");

      return false;
    });
```

Also, it looked like you had an extra (trailing) comma after your `focus` declaration.  Might want to clean that up.

**UPDATE**

After playing around with your code a bit in jsbin.com, I think I found the solution to your specific issue with IE, but I'm not 100% on why it only dies in IE.

Example: http://jsbin.com/aqituk/2/edit#javascript,html

The difference was changing the `$(function() { ...` to the full document ready function, `$(document).ready(function() {...`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try adding the "return false" as per your example, however I think you meant to add this in the focus event of the input field, rather than the autocomplete focus event?

Comment: Updated with an example of when it works and when it doesn't in IE9

Comment: Good catch with the IE9 issue. I've only been testing in up to version 8 to date. Maybe I didn't explain well enough but the alerts in your solution were affecting the functionality of the auto complete for me. I don't want the [inputElement].focus() to fire when I click on an item in the menu e.g. I enter "J", click on "JavaScript" and "JavaScript" should now be the value of the text field. I've updated my question with the solution. I tweaked what was originally your suggestion, so please could you update your answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Autocomplete demo</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
            select: function(event, ui){
               var yourTxt= $(this);
               yourTxt.value = ui.item.value;

           }
        });

        $("#tags").mouseup(function () {
            // clear the input value
            $("#tags").val("");
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" value="Enter your keywords..."/>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just been tired to solve for same matter.
Finally, I've just taken simple solution shown below:

```
// onload
$('#foo').autofocus({
    // add options
    disabled: true
});

<input id="foo" onclick="$(this).autocomplete('enable');">
```

Comment: I tried this but `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autofocus is not a function(…)`